# Eclipse plugin not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I developed an Eclipse plugin that compiles and runs java code in German. The technique I am using is that I translate the code to English and pass it to Java Compiler and get the results back and print it in the console. 
The problem is that the plugin works when I run the plugin from Inside Eclipse but when I install the plugin in Eclipse so that when I open Eclipse it already exists there and start to test if a real user uses my plugin and creates a new Java project and try to the compile button in my plugin it says [The chosen operation is not currently available] ![Here is the the way I run and it opens a new Eclipse application with the installed plugin ]

Any help please

Comment: how did you install your plugin to eclipse? check your "installed plugins" view and check if it is really there. If so, check if there is an error log entry and post it here

Comment: I've extracted my Plugin project as a ZIP folder and then opened the Eclipse directory and uncompressed the zip file and pasted it in Eclipse/dropins

Comment: @moeTi what do you think ?

Comment: see the second part of my comment. is it installed, is there something in the error log?

Comment: @moeTi No nothing appears in the log .. it's just that it's not working when I install it inside Eclipse .. Is the way of installation incorrect ?

Answer (score 0):

the way you installed your plugin sounds a little weird to me. So at first please try to export your plugin via the Export Wizard.
(Select `Export -> Deployable plugins and features` from your projects context menu)

Export your project as jar file and copy it to the 'plugin' folder of your eclipse instance.

After that it might be helpful to debug your plugin on OSGI-Level as there might be a problem loading your plugin (at least the error description you have posted indicates that).

Run eclipse with `-console -noExit -consoleLog` flags to open an OSGI console for debugging. After that try running `ss <your-plugin-name>` to see what the state of your plugin is.

The output gives you the ID of your plugin and the state it currently has. If the state of your plugin is not `ACTIVE` try running `start <your-plugin-id>` to see whether it starts correctly. If there is a problem starting your plugin you should get a respective log message. Feel free to post it here in case you need further help.
Otherwise there are plenty of options what might cause your problems, so maybe its better to try the steps I have described above before getting into details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run eclipse plug-in withput using Eclipse Application , then you need to make a Feature project.

> Now if your algorithm has something to do with system Path , you must
>   check Unpack plug-in and you should read the resource accordingly.
>   Like PLatformUI.getWorkBC() etc..

No other eclipse plug-in (jar) should be inside plugins directory of eclipse of same name of your plug-in. Ensure for this.